# Collapsed Menu only partially visible

Tags: jquery, css, templates, joomla

In my site www.dallazaira.it I have a problem with mobile template. When I 
click to menu button it appear but I see only the first menu item.

I try all the css and jquery in all post and i try 
to modify css for hours but I cannot find a solution. Can you help me on 
that?
Thank you!

```
The html when closed is:
<nav class=" bd-hmenu-1" data-responsive-menu="true" data-responsive-levels="">
<div class=" bd-menuitem-10 collapse-button"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bd-hmenu-1 .collapse-button + .navbar-collapse" href="#" onclick="return false;" class="collapsed"><span></span></a></div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
<div class=" bd-horizontalmenu-1 clearfix">
<div class="bd-container-inner">
<ul class=" bd-menu-1 nav navbar-left nav-pills nav-pills">
<li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-101 current"><a class="  active" href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>                        
<li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-125"><a href="/prodotti"><span>Prodotti</span></a></li>                        
<li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-124"><a href="/gallery"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>                        
<li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-108"><a href="/dove-siamo"><span>Dove siamo</span></a></li>                        
<li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-109"><a href="/contattaci"><span>Contattaci</span></a></li>
</ul>    
</div>
</div>        
</div>
</nav>
```

The html when open is:

```
<nav class=" bd-hmenu-1" data-responsive-menu="true" data-responsive-levels="">
 <div class=" bd-menuitem-10 collapse-button"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bd-hmenu-1 .collapse-button + .navbar-collapse" href="#" onclick="return false;" class=""><span></span></a></div>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
   <div class=" bd-horizontalmenu-1 clearfix">
    <div class="bd-container-inner">
     <ul class=" bd-menu-1 nav navbar-left nav-pills nav-pills">
      <li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-101 current"><a class="  active" href="/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
      <li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-125"><a href="/prodotti"><span>Prodotti</span></a></li>                        
      <li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-124"><a href="/gallery"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>                        
      <li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-108"><a href="/dove-siamo"><span>Dove siamo</span></a></li>                        
      <li class=" bd-menuitem-3 item-109"><a href="/contattaci"><span>Contattaci</span></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>        
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried?  You will get far better responses with a specific question, at the moment this one is way too open ended.

Comment: I post the link to the site so you can inspect the page, i think is more simple. I add the html. The template is a free joomla template. If you need somtehing tell me. Thanks

Comment: I posted a solution. But this is bad question for stack overflow. As your question does not fully reflect the problem. And it can only by solved by actually looking at your page. So I will vote to delete it. Next time please create an minimal, verfiable example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

If you want to help other people, you really should report the problem to the template maker, unless the problem was only created through your custom CSS.

Comment: Thank for the solution. But in this case menu go over the carousel. The problem is the content don't push down when open the menu on mobile like other responsive menu. Template maker doesn't answer to any mail. I like stack overflow but i think it can be more simple for all user. If for verifiable i have to copy html, css, jquery etc on this site i lost a lot of time that i can spend to find a solution or call a friend, it's my thought. I prefer to inspect problem personally, it's more simple. You can delete the post and thanks again for your answer, your time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should always inspect the elements in the browser developer tools. Then you would see, that the menu:

- is hidden behind your carousel
- has no background-color

So the element is there, it is just not visible.

So you should add some css like:

```
.navbar-collapse {
  z-index: 100;
  background: white;
}
```

But really your main lesson here, should be to start learning how to use the [browser developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), so you can pinpoint the problem exactly.